# How to use a specific version of a native library using DLLIMPORT

Tags: c#, interop, native, dllimport

I have two (or more) versions of my native C++ library with their file paths added to PATH variable. My .NET application uses DLLIMPORT attribute to reference methods inside the native dlls. The problem is that DLLIMPORT in .NET application picks whichever native library it finds FIRST so my two different versions of the same .NET application end up using the same version of native dll.

```
[DllImport("MyNative.dll")]
private static extern int SomeFunc();
```

I was wondering if there is a way to tell DLLIMPORT to pick a specific version of native dll OR maybe use some event to guide it to the right dll? Using the full path in DLLIMPORT does not seem like a solution.

Comment: if you can modify the native C++ library, why not just update the method name or signature to differentiate the two APIs? Like SomeFunc vs. SomeFuncEx? Maybe you are just trying to find a possible way, but I would not playing with the DLL versioning techniques, they had already caused too many headaches to me.

Comment: A new version of native dll comes every 6 months so changing the function names with every new version of the native dll is not an option for me.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to invite DLL Hell into your program.  Relying on the PATH environment variable is indeed an excellent way.  Just don't, the days that sharing DLLs was useful are long gone.  Give the program its own copy.

Comment: The .NET assembly that references the native DLL using DLLIMPORT is installed in the GAC and is used as API dll by other applications so I cannot put the native dll along with the assembly.